# Trouble installing openpyxl

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am having a great deal of difficulty installing the **openpyxl** library on my version of python 3.6 at work. The problem is that I use python36 located in `C:\program files`, however the pip installs packages in `C:\Anaconda\Lib`. I tried using the `--target=PATH` flag to select where pip would install, but that caused an error about privileges. I also tried just copying the **openpyxl** folder from one location to the other, but again, no admin privileges.

My last thought was to download the .tar.gz file(which I did) and manually extract to the correct location without using pip, but I don't really know how to do that.

I would just call IT and have them install the package for me, but I'm new and my paperwork for an employee number hasn't gone through yet, and they told me they can't do anything until it does.

If anyone could help me figure out a workaround, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two versions of python installed - one via Anaconda in the `C:\Anaconda\` directory and one in `C:\program files\`. Generally, it is easier to manage your packages through Anaconda and use the Anaconda-provided python. If you really want to use the version in `C:\program files\` AND have admin privileges, you can run the python script at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py with the system python to install pip, then explicitly use that pip version to install openpyxl for that python.

The alternative is to use the Anaconda python by default by adjusting your `PATH` to find that python installation first. This should avoid the permission issues and versioning headaches from trying to run two different python installations at the same time.